# Can't find certain package in Package control: Install Package

Tags: sublimetext3

I can't find this package in Package control. Looks like my list is outdated.
https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime
How can i fix it?

Sublime Text 3083

Comment: Having the exact same problem with the same package on Sublime Text 2. Package is on packagecontrol.io but doesn't show up in Package Control in Sublime :/. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem with a different package, this is the only result I found when searching so I'll post my answer.

**I already had the package installed!**

I apparently installed it previously then forgot I had done so. Check your packages list if you can't find one! Command Palette > Package Control: List Packages

Answer (score 18):

Not sure what the issue with Sublime is, but if anyone else gets stuck on this you can just install from Github directly. Works for babel-sublime and should work for other packages.

**1) Find the relevant repo (assuming open source)**

```
https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime
```

**2) Clone into your packages folder**

On a mac this would be

```
$ cd /Users/(username)/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/  
$ git clone https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime
```

---

And that was it for me - restart Sublime Text and the package is available.

Comment: Having the same issue with ExportHtml package, but am new to ST3 and have read several warnings about not using Package Control (usually followed by a comment about manual installs not updating with future releases). What happens with this particular process?

Comment: Same issue sublime text 3

Answer (score 16):

- Open Package Control Options(Commad+Shift+P) and add the repository if its not exist.
- Open Package Control Again and choose Install package and write the package name which in your case its (babel-sublime) and you should find it.

[image]

Comment: I tried this for the [ExportHtml Package](https://github.com/facelessuser/ExportHtml). It said the repository was added successfully, but the package still couldn't be found. Tried restart etc, but just can't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try restarting, or may be issue with the package itself.

Comment: As mentioned, tried restarting. Contacted package manager & he said he could not replicate the problem. Have gone with manual install for time being.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to install babel-sublime but it is not included in package control it is in GitHub repository, it can be added manually.

1. Go to *Preferences > Package Control*
2. In the command palette, type `Package Control: Add Repository`
3. A text box will appear at the bottom, paste the URL to the repository, i.e. `https://github.com/username/repo`.

Now that you have added the GitHub repository, you can add the package as you would have originally:

4. Go to *Preferences > Package Control*
5. In the Command Palette, type `Package Control: Install Package`
6. In the dialog box, type the name of your package, i.e. `babel-sublime` Auto complete will find if it is present. If that is the case, press enter and wait for it to install, then restart sublime. It will be installed upon restart.

PS: the same way to install any package from GitHub
you can Google *sublime plugins* to find some really cool ones

Comment: This. Totally this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to add it 2 times, each time closing. Then it finally worked and got all packages. Thats the only solution i found. Some glitch in Sublime.

Heres is info how to install full packages list https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3, go to View, Show Console. Paste in the code below and hit Enter.

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 
'df21e130d211cfc94d9b0905775a7c0f' + 
'1e3d39e33b79698005270310898eea76'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-
package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); 
urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( 
urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 
'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = 
hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got 
%s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h 
else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

the solution was found here:
http://www.storybench.org/install-babel-packages-sublime-text-3/

Answer (score 0):

My version of Sublime Text 3 was old.  I solved this problem by simply running the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which will update sublime after sublime v 3.0, restarted sublime, and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

1. open command pallette
2. Package Control: install package -> enter
3. you search Babel -> enter

good luck